# How to match the ITEM with a record in the database?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have storing URLs in a database table:

```
 scrapy_id  | scrapy_name   |    url    
------------+---------------+-----------------
        111 |       aaa     |  http://url1.com   
        222 |       bbb     |  http://url2.com 
        333 |       ccc     |  http://url3.com
```

I need start request from the urls, so I initial the database connection in open_spider of pipeline:

```
class PgsqlPipeline(object):

...

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(database=self.XXX, user=self.XXX, password=self.XXX)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        spider.myPipeline = self

    def get_urls(self):
        get_urls_sql = """
        SOME_SQL_STATMENTS
        """

        self.cur.execute(get_urls_sql)
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

...
```

then, in spider:

```
....

class SephoraSpider(Spider):
    name = 'XXX'
    allowed_domains = ['XXX']

    def start_requests(self):
        for row in self.myPipeline.get_urls():
            self.item = SomeItem()
            url = str(row[2])
            self.item['id'] = row[0]
            self.item['name'] = row[1]
            yield Request(self.url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.item['text'] = response.xpath('XXXX').get()
        return self.item

....
```

in items:

```
....

class SomeItem(Item):
    id = Field()
    name = Field()
    text = Field()
....
```

I want to get following item:

```
{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "aaa",
    "text": response1,
},
{
    "id": 222,
    "name": "bbb",
    "text": response2,
},
{
    "id": 333,
    "name": "ccc",
    "text": response3,
}
```

But I get:

```
{
    "id": 333,
    "name": "ccc",
    "text": response1,
},
{
    "id": 333,
    "name": "ccc",
    "text": response2,
},
{
    "id": 333,
    "name": "ccc",
    "text": response3,
}
```

The problem may be that I put `self.item = SomeItem()` in start_requests(), But if I put `self.item = SomeItem()` in parse_item(), I can not get `id` and `name`, It means that cannot **match** the resolved response with its ID.

How to match the ITEM with a record in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `self` to store the request metadata because you are setting it only while starting the requests; you need the data to be persisted with the request, not with the `SephoraSpider` class instance. In the `parse_item` callback, it will just be set to the value of the last request you started. Instead, you can use the `Request.meta` field:

```
class SephoraSpider(Spider):
    name = 'XXX'
    allowed_domains = ['XXX']

    def start_requests(self):
        for row in self.myPipeline.get_urls():
            url = str(row[2])
            item = {'id': row[0], 'name': row[1], 'url': row[2]}
            yield Request(self.url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['text'] = response.xpath('XXXX').get()
        return item
```

Details in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta).

Comment: YES. But there was a small typo: `meta: {'item': item}` should be `meta={'item': item}`

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it.